# Spark-Not submitting jobs to nodes in cluster

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-system

I have done spark setup in standalone cluster mode (Windows 7).
I am able to register 2 nodes and verify the same on spark UI.
But when I submit a job, its status always remain as WAITING.

There is no firewall issue or permission issue for log/work directory for worker nodes.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: can you share relevant parts of the command lines you use to start master and executors?

Comment: Hi Michel, I have followed below steps to start master and workers..
1. Run spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master to run the master. This will give you a URL of the form spark://ip:port

2. Run spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://ip:port -m 6g   to run the worker. Make sure you use the URL you obtained in step 1.

Comment: Did you try to just spark-shell to your spark master url?  (and validate a new application is running in localhost:8080).  Another thing to look at is the number of resources.  When spark-submitting your job, are you specifying the number of cores/memory to get from your local cluster?

Comment: do you have enough resources to allocate according to the configs you set for your job? The reason may has been aroused because you have set more resources to your executors than which is usable on your system. for example you may have just 4g ram space but you have set it to 6g.

Comment: I am able to run jobs on cluster. Its similar to what epcpu mentioned. I have workers with 6g ram but i was setting spark.executor.memory to be 8g. Thanks for your help epcpu and Michel.

Answer (score 0):

I did some test on my local machine (windows 10 with WSL):

1. Started the master: `./sbin/start-master.sh`
2. Started a slave with master url: `./sbin/start-slave.sh`
3. Submitted sparkpi example and app is waiting:
   `./spark-submit --executor-cores 64 --master spark://[master-hostname]:7077 --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi ../examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0.jar`
4. Submitted sparkpi example and app completes:
   `./spark-submit --executor-cores 4 --master spark://[master-hostname]:7077 --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi ../examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0.jar`

So as epcpu and I have said, you might only be requesting too much resources on your cluster and the resource manager waits until they become available.